# Nginx keepalive directive maybe not working

Tags: http, nginx, keep-alive, ddos

i'm using nginx as a front end server, mostly to serve static files and to do load balancing. I am using keepalive_timeout 15 directive. But there is samething that i don't understand. My webapp's home page do lot's of requests, about 80. There are several images, thumbnails, javascript and css files etc.. now, if keepalive will mantain open the connection between clients and server, why when a client ask for my homepage, there are 80 open connection for 15 sec? I discover this using netstat or tcptrack..

My problem is that i'm tryng to prevent small (d)dos attacks with ddos defilate, that run periodically a netstat command that check how many connection are opened for each client ip and ban all ips that have more then "myvariable" connections opened.. But if someone ask for home page, then for another page and then for another, if he do it very fast, there will be 150+ opened connection because for each http request there is a connection opened for 15 seconds, and i want avoid it. Maybe i'm not understanding something?

Answer (score 0):

Put keepalive off; and use Nginx's rate limiting module.

Comment: with keepalive off i am sure to create a new connection for each req..and i want to avoid it! i'm using limit_req_module for preventing flood. I can limit much the number of parrallel connections from the same client but in this way my server will be slow..i simply want that keepalive directive will work good :D :D